# Splits on different monitors

Tags: neovim, split

I'd like to edit the same file at two different locations, let's say at the beginning and at the end of the file.

Splits (`:sp`) are a natural way to do this.

I have two monitors available and it sure would be convenient to have each split on a different monitor.

For example, is there a way to break out a split into its own window so I can move the window to the other monitor with my window manager ([Sway](https://swaywm.org/))?

I'm looking for a solution that preferably doesn't rely on plugins, like [vim-multiple-monitors](https://github.com/codeape2/vim-multiple-monitors).

I'm using Neovim 0.6.1.

Answer (score 3):

You have an OS window and you have a vim window. A normal instance of vim can't live in 2 different OS windows. However, two clients attached to the same server can live in different OS windows.

Since you are using `nvim`, the syntax is different. You can start `nvim` as a server. It will listen on a socket you define: `nvim --listen ~/.cache/nvim/server.pipe`.

And then the other window just needs to open up a client to this server.

```
Start an Nvim server listening on a named pipe at '~/.cache/nvim/server.pipe': >
    nvim --listen ~/.cache/nvim/server.pipe

Edit "file.txt" in an Nvim server listening at '~/.cache/nvim/server.pipe': >
    nvim --server ~/.cache/nvim/server.pipe
```

Now you have 2 instances of vim that're editing the same file. This is not how you're supposed to use this, but... whatever. `nvim` will automatically load all changes written in one buffer to the other. You just have to say "Edit Anyway" when the "This file is already being edited" error message pops up.

I do NOT recommend doing this, but it worked for me, and who am I to judge :)... The screen won't be updated it gains focus, unlike vim-native windowed splits.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Using `--servername` is not possible in Neovim currently since it doesn't implement `+clientserver`. See also [this](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch/issues/163).

Comment: @Rich You're right, the command should have been `--listen`. I will edit my answer